# How to use double Buffered AWT Animations in Java

Tags: java, animation, double, buffer, awt

I have recently begun working with double buffering in Java. I have read tutorials that have shown me how to display images and move them using mouse and keyboard events. However this is where I become confused. My program is simple, there is a rectangle at the bottom of my window that is movable by LEFT and RIGHT key events. However I can not figure out for the life of my how to draw another shape onto the screen by an event and continue buffering it.

I would like to be able to push a key to draw a "missile" (which in my case would be a small Oval) at the X and Y position of the rectangle I have drawn already, and have it fire upwards. Much like any classic space shooter.

This however is not as much of a specific, concrete problem of mine, but a concept I do not understand. I learned how to do many of the similar things in Lua, however when it came to drawing new images after initialization or an image upon key events, I was stumped.

My question is this: In what order of Java's init(), stop(), destroy(), start(), run(), paint(), and update() cycle do I use to buffer a new shape/image onto the screen from a key event?

I have searched many tutorials with example code, but with no avail. I have been learning Java for nearly 8 months now, but no matter how basic or simple I try to understand something, it's as if even the most primordial tutorial requires prerequisite knowledge.

My code is as follows.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SquareApplet extends Applet implements Runnable
{
        int x_pos = 10;
        int y_pos = 400;

        int rectX = 50;
        int rectY = 20;

        int x_speed = 5;

        private Image dbImage;
        private Graphics dbg;


        public void init( ) { }

        //public void start() { }

        public void stop( ) { }

        public void destroy( ) { }

        //public void run ( ) { }

        //public void paint (Graphics g) { }        

    public void start()
    {
        // define a new thread 
        Thread th = new Thread (this);
        // start this thread
        th.start ();
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        // lower ThreadPriority 
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        // run a long while (true) this means in our case "always"
        while (true) //Runtime
        {

            if (x_pos > this.getSize().width - rectX) {x_pos = this.getSize().width - rectX;}
            if (x_pos < 0) {x_pos = 0 ;}

            // repaint the applet
            repaint();


            try
            {
                // Stop thread for 20 milliseconds
                Thread.sleep (20);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException beepis)
            {
                // do nothing
            }

            // set ThreadPriority to maximum value
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        // set background color
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
        // set player color
        g.setColor (Color.white);

        // paint a filled colored rectangle
        g.fillRect(x_pos, y_pos, rectX,rectY );        
    }

    public void update (Graphics g)
    {
        // initialize buffer
        if (dbImage == null)
        {
            dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics ();
        }

        // clear screen in background
        dbg.setColor (getBackground ());
        dbg.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        // draw elements in background
        dbg.setColor (getForeground());
        paint (dbg);

        // draw image on the screen
        g.drawImage (dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }    
    //KEY EVENTS
    public boolean keyDown(Event e, int key)
    {

        //Up Down Left Right
        if (key == Event.LEFT)
        {
            x_pos -= x_speed;
        }

        if (key == Event.RIGHT)    
        {
            x_pos += x_speed;
        }           
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How to use double Buffered AWT.."*  Get a time machine & go back to last millennium when people used & knew AWT?  Alternately join us in the 3rd millennium & use Swing instead.  Swing is double buffered by default (and people remember how to use it).